# Array Definition Differences In VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use ANSYS Maxwell Scripting via VBscript but I have a problem with the array definitions.

```
oModule.EditSetup "ParametricSetup1", Array("NAME:ParametricSetup1", "IsEnabled:=",  _
  true, Array("NAME:ProdOptiSetupDataV2", "SaveFields:=", false, "CopyMesh:=", false, "SolveWithCopiedMeshOnly:=",  _
  false), Array("NAME:StartingPoint"), "Sim. Setups:=", Array("Setup1"), Array("NAME:Goals", _
  _ 
  Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=", _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=", _
  Goals(i), "Name:=", "Goal" & cstr(i), Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a"))), _
  Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=", _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=", _
  "avg(100 - Efficiency)", "Name:=", "Efficiency", Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a"))), _
  Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=",  _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=",  _
  "avg(MassTotal)", "Name:=", "MassTotal", Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a"))), _
  Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=",  _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=",  _
  "max(PhaseVoltage)", "Name:=", "PhaseVoltage", Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a"))), _
  Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=",  _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=",  _
  "max(TorqueRipple)", "Name:=", "TorqueRipple", Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a"))), _
  Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=",  _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=",  _
  "avg(st_length)", "Name:=", "StackLength", Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a"))), _ 
  Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=",  _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=",  _
  "avg(L_q)/avg(L_d)", "Name:=", "Saliency", Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a")))))
```

This code is automatically generated via ANSYS and works great, however, I want to give the goals from variables in VBS so I wrote this.

```
Dim ArrS : ArrS = ArraySize + 1
Dim ANSYSGoals()
Redim ANSYSGoals(ArrS)
ANSYSGoals(0) = "NAME:Goals"
For i = 1 to ArraySize Step 1
  ANSYSGoals(i) = Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=", _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=", _
  Goals(i-1), "Name:=", "Goal" & cstr(i-1), Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a")))
Next


oModule.EditSetup "ParametricSetup1", Array("NAME:ParametricSetup1", "IsEnabled:=",  _
  true, ANSYSGoals)
```

Although ANSYS accepts This kind of arrays (I had a code that does a similar thing but that code work) this piece of code is not working. However, if I change the code to this:

```
Dim ArrS : ArrS = ArraySize + 1
Dim ANSYSGoals()
Redim ANSYSGoals(ArrS)
ANSYSGoals(0) = "NAME:Goals"
For i = 1 to ArraySize Step 1
  ANSYSGoals(i) = Array("NAME:Goal", "ReportType:=", "Transient", "Solution:=", _
  "Setup1 : Transient", Array("NAME:SimValueContext", "Domain:=", "Sweep"), "Calculation:=", _
  Goals(i-1), "Name:=", "Goal" & cstr(i-1), Array("NAME:Ranges", "Range:=", Array("Var:=",  _
  "Time", "Type:=", "a")))
Next

oModule.EditSetup "ParametricSetup1", Array("NAME:ParametricSetup1", "IsEnabled:=",  _
  true, Array(ANSYSGoals(0),ANSYSGoals(1),ANSYSGoals(2)))
```

It works. So my question is what is the difference between the 3 item array `ANSYSGoals` and `Array(ANSYSGoals(0), ANSYSGoals(1), ANSYSGoals(2))`?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: The difference is the latter is another `Array()` wrapper around the existing arrays.

Comment: I want to specify the size of the array by the ArraySize variable and using that wrapper creates a problem about it, so what kind of solution I should apply?